# Angular 4 proper way to cast http response

Tags: angular

I've created a service in Angular 4 and I'm fetching data via REST/JSON (new to Angular) using this code:

Interface

```
export interface IItem {
    Id: number;
    Title: string;
}
```

Service

```
import { IItem } from './item';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ItemTest {

    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

    getItems(): Observable<IItem[]> {
        return this._http.get<IItem[]>('url')
            .do(data => {
                console.log(data);
            })
    }
}
```

The http cast to IITem works fine if the response is in this format

```
[
    {
        "Id": 53,
        "Title": "Test Document 4.docx"
    },
    {
        "Id": 55,
        "Title": "Test Document 2.docx"
    }
]
```

But the actual response from the server looks like this and the cast doesn't work.  What's the best way to cast the "results" portion of the response to an array of IItems?

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "Id": 53,
                "Title": "Test Document 4.docx"
            },
            {
                "Id": 55,
                "Title": "Test Document 2.docx"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Type assertions **are not** casting anything. They're just telling the compiler what you expect. If you need to actually convert the response, you should do that explicitly, and if you want the types to be any help at all the specific type should *actually match what you expect*, in this case `.get<{ d: { results: IItem[] } }>(...)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Registering a DLL from a TFS Build using a CodeActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669846/registering-a-dll-from-a-tfs-build-using-a-codeactivity)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried that option but the compiler complained that "Type '{ d: { results: IItem[]; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IItem[]'."

Comment: Yes, of course it does, **because it isn’t**. You don’t get an array, you get an object. The typing of the get should describe the shape of the JSON you expect to receive, not what you intend to transform it to.

Comment: Could you please review the answers and consider accepting mine; it's the only one that actually tells you how to solve this problem in a way where the compiler can help you out, and has been pushed below answers that are incomplete or inaccurate.

Comment: Yes, sorry I posted this and forgot about it because I was extremely busy at the time. I'm reviewing the thread now.

Answer (score 1):

Youll want to use the map operator:

```
@Injectable()
export class ItemTest {

    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

    getItems(): Observable<IItem[]> {
        return this._http.get('url').map((data) => data['d']['results'])              
            .do(data => {
                console.log(data);
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: `.get<IItem[]>` is **not** correct, so this will fail to compile

Comment: @jonrsharpe good catch, I am just hoping to show generally how to do it. Likely there are other reasons it wont compile as well.

Comment: This solved the problem with a small change.  I had to enclose the map options in quotes  .map((data) => data['d']['results'])   otherwise the compiler complained that "Property 'd' does not exist on type 'IItem[]'"   (I tried to vote it as the answer but it won't display it)

Comment: @Nillac that’s because **it is the wrong type**. If you’re going to do that you might as well not specify it at all.

Answer (score 1):

The specific type for the get should describe the shape of the actual response JSON you expect to receive. Then the compiler can *actually help you* by telling you whether you’re accessing and returning the right things. In your case:

```
getItems(): Observable<IItem[]> {
    return this._http.get<{ d: { results: IItem[] } }>('url')
        .map(response => response.d.results)
        .do(data => {
            console.log(data);
        }):
}
```

Note that none of this is *casting* the response data, just *describing* it.

---

As for your other suggestion:

```
.get<IItem[]>(...)
.map((data) => data['d']['results'])
```

If you’re going to assert the type of the response wrongly then make unsafe property accesses with a result the compiler can only assume is `any`, you might as well not be using types at all. Don’t just ignore the compiler when it tells you you’re accessing the wrong properties.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes here - this answer is solid

Comment: @Luca appreciate it, I did [ask the OP to review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46717706/angular-4-proper-way-to-cast-http-response#comment82817505_46717706) but no joy.

Comment: Strangely, I can't mark this as answered. The option doesn't show up even though it's there for my other questions.

Comment: @jpwrunyan eh? You didn't ask this question.

Comment: That explains everything. Including my amnesia.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to run a few mapping utilities

```
http.get(url)
.map(response => response.json())
.map(response => response.d.results)
.map(results => results.map(item => return Object.create(IItem, item))
```

Comment: OP is using the http client api, so the response doesnt have a json() method.

Comment: Correct, json() method doesn't exist