# Angular4 - why does custom toJSON() only get called on new objects?

Tags: json, angular, stringify

I have this code. Notice that the serialization is simply renaming the template_items property to template_items_attributes:

```
export class Template {
  constructor(
  ) {}

  public id: string
  public account_id: string
  public name: string
  public title: string
  public info: string
  public template_items: Array<TemplateItem>

  toJSON(): ITemplateSerialized {
    return {
      id: this.id,
      account_id: this.account_id,
      name: this.name,
      title: this.title,
      info: this.info,
      template_items_attributes: this.template_items
    }
  }
}


export interface ITemplateSerialized {
  id: string,
  account_id: string,
  name: string,
  title: string,
  info: string,
  template_items_attributes: Array<TemplateItem>
}
```

Creating an object locally works fine and stringify calls the toJSON() method.

However, once I send that object to the API:

```
  private newTemplate(name: string): Template {
    let template = new Template();
    template.name = name;
    template.account_id = this._userService.user.account_id;
    // next 5 lines are for testing that toJSON() is called on new obj
    let item = new TemplateItem();
    item.content = "Test"
    template.template_items.push(item);
    let result = JSON.stringify(template);
    console.log('ready', result); // SHOWS the property changes
    return template;
  }

  postTemplate(name: string): Observable<any> {
    return this._authService.post('templates', JSON.stringify(this.newTemplate(name)))
      .map((response) => {
        return response.json();
      });
  }
```

It is saved and returned, but from that point on when I stringify and save again it does NOT call toJSON().

```
  patchTemplate(template: Template): Observable<any> {
    console.log('patching', JSON.stringify(template)); // DOES NOT CHANGE!
    return this._authService.patch('templates' + `/${template.id}`, JSON.stringify(template))
      .map((response) => {
        return response.json();
      });
  }
```

Why does toJSON() only work on new objects?

Comment: Post the code hidden behind "once I send that object to the API, save and return it, from that point on when I stringify and save again it does NOT call toJSON()".

Comment: At a guess, because you're not actually converting the API response back into a `Template` instance, leaving at as a regular object that has the right *properties* but none of the *methods*.

Comment: For those who want to understand this more, it seems the way to go is to use Decorators and Reflectors. Full discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885995/how-do-i-initialize-a-typescript-object-with-a-json-object

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45844055/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/46839214/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/46717706/3001761. It seems to be quite a common misconception.

Comment: There is an experimental feature in Typescript for this here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Decorators.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, your question has nothing to do with Angular or Typescript, it's just some JavaScript and the logic of how serialization work and *why* do we serialize objects.

> I send that object to the API, save and return it

When you return an "object" from an API, you're returning a string which you parse as a JSON serialized object. Then you get a *plain* JavaScript object, *not* an instance of your class.

`Object` prototype in JavaScript does not have `toJSON` method, and even if it had, it's not the method you've written inside the `Template` class, so it won't be called.

You don't even need a server call to replicate this, just do

```
const obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(new Template()))
obj.toJSON // undefined
```

And you'll see that `obj` is not an instance of `Template`. It's simply an object which simply happens to have all the fields as your original object made as a `Template` instance, but it's *not* an instance of that class.

Comment: Thanks. Stupid me thought classes in Typescript would behave like C# or Java classes. I just read some blogs, now I understand. Thanks for the explanation.